# Make http request to external api in nestjs

Tags: api, axios, request, nestjs, http-post

Below you will find my file nestjs service, here I make 3 get requests, one for authentication and another 2 to consult other services, in the get cases they work correctly, I can even use the authentication service in the other two get requests, in the post I get It seems I'm not handling the body that I have to send well and it generates an error:

```
[Nest] 66147  - 04/24/2023, 6:10:14 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Converting circular structure to JSON`
--> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
|     property 'res' -> object with constructor 'IncomingMessage'
--- property 'req' closes the circle
```

**My code:**

```
import { Injectable, InternalServerErrorException } from '@nestjs/common';
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
import { CreateAppointmentDto } from './dto/create-appointment.dto';
import { GetSchedulerDTO } from './dto/get-scheduler.dto';
import { SchedulerResponse } from './interfaces/schedulers-response.interface';

const BASE_URL = 'http://url.to.meke.http.pos.get.request/api';
const keyWS = 'keyWS_token'

@Injectable()
export class SchedulerService {

  private readonly axios: AxiosInstance = axios;
  
  async generateToken(){
    const token = await this.axios.post(
      `${BASE_URL}/token`,
      {
        Username: process.env.USER_NAME,
        Password: process.env.PASSWORD,
      }
    )
    return token.data;
  }  
  
  async getScheduler(getSchedulerDTO: GetSchedulerDTO){
    try {
      const extToken = await this.generateToken();
      const data = getSchedulerDTO;
      const schedulerResponse = await this.axios.get<SchedulerResponse>(
        `${BASE_URL}/Appointment/GetScheduler/${keyWS}/${data.idExam}/${data.initialDate} 00:00/${data.lastDate} 23:59`, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${extToken}`
          }
        }
      )
      return schedulerResponse.data;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException('No se encontro disponibilidad para esta agenda');
    }
  }

  async getExams(){
    const extToken = await this.generateToken();
    const getExams = await this.axios.get(
      `${BASE_URL}/Appointment/GetListsForAppointments/Exams/${keyWS}`, {
        headers:{ Authorization: `Bearer ${extToken}` },
      }
    )
    return getExams.data;
  }

  async getInsurances(){
    const extToken = await this.generateToken();
    const getInsurances = await this.axios.get(
      `${BASE_URL}/Appointment/GetListsForAppointments/insurances/${keyWS}`,
      {
        headers:{
          Authorization: `Bearer ${extToken}`
        }
      }
    )
    return getInsurances.data;
  }

  async choiceAppointment( createAppointmentDto:CreateAppointmentDto ){
    try {
      const extToken = await this.generateToken();
      const  resp  = await this.axios.post(
        `${BASE_URL}/Appointment/CreateAppointment`,
        {
          headers:{ Authorization: `Bearer ${extToken}` },
          body: { ...createAppointmentDto }
        }
      )
      return resp.data
    } catch(error){
      return error.response
    }
    
  }  


}
```

Comment: Somewhere you are returning a `req` or a `ClientRequest` object that is circular upon itself. The stack trace may be useful here, or extra context of the code, like the controller code